# Facebook Messenger Postback

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a very interesting and annoying issue. I build a Facebook messenger bot ... everything worked fine. I have a webhook connected to my NodeJS server. Again everything is fie till I got to the "final touch" of the project, the Persistent Menu.

I added a Persistent Menu with the following command

```
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type" : "call_to_actions",
  "thread_state" : "existing_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "type":"postback",
      "title":"Estimate an app cost",
      "payload":"startEstimation"
    },
    {
      "type":"postback",
      "title":"Get in touch",
      "payload":"getInTouch"
    },
    {
      "type":"web_url",
      "title":"View Website",
      "url":"http://whatever.com"
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=BLA"
```

Again here everything worked fine I even got the  `{"result":"Successfully added structured menu CTAs"}` answer and now I HAVE MY MENU. The only problem is that when I click one of the postback buttons .. nothing happens.

Facts:

- I made my sever to print some logs on the first line of the post api:

  app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {   console.log("Smth came frm the
  hook =>", req.body);

  -> It works if I post with Postman. It works for the buttons
  inside the conversation when I have a button with a postback I get
  the answer BUT FOR THE MENU IT DOES NOTHING. I don't get any logs at
  all. Like Facebook never triggers my hook.
- In the Page Subscription Fields I added all of them .. that's how desperate the situation is lol.
- Everything else with the bot works fine. Any other button/text messages/postbacks work just fine.
- My code is forked from here: https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-facebook
  and this is the webhook https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-facebook/blob/master/src/app.js#L431

What on Earth could I miss ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout new Persistent menu requirements.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/persistent-menu

It has changed a little bit (especially POST request), so probably that's the problem.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for lol :) I have the webhook api already implemented. Can't you see the github code I linked ?

Comment: Sorry, I skipped part wiith Github ;)

Comment: Yeah no worries .. but I still need some help :(

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check out new FB requirements, they've changed API for persistent menu.

Comment: Oh my God .. that was it lol :|. I've spammed google with search requests those days and didn't find anything about the new api. Thanks a lot dude

Comment: I've got that error today. Can you put the key word: "Your app must  the pages_messaging permission" to your answer? I think it will help some people save their time ^^